How to find which code directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed
I'm training a three-layer model, and I get an error when using loss.backward() to calculate the gradient during the training process.**RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed).**However I am not using backward() twice in the same round of training.
My training process is as follows：
for _ in tqdm(range(inner_iters)):
            idx_batch_eval = torch.randint(low=0, high=idx_range, size=(batch_size,),  
                                                                  dtype=torch.int32)
            train_states = target_set[idx_batch_eval]
            train_level = c
            train_roa_labels = target_labels[idx_batch_eval]  # 确定他们的标签
            class_weights, class_counts = balanced_class_weights(train_roa_labels.astype(bool), 
                                                                          scale_by_total=True)

            def loss(value,nn_train_value):
                class_labels = 2 * train_roa_labels - 1
                decision_distance = train_level - value
                class_labels_torch = torch.tensor(class_labels, dtype=torch.float64)
                class_weights_torch = torch.tensor(class_weights, dtype=torch.float64)
                # 创建一个300行1列的全0矩阵，数据类型为float64
                zero_matrix = torch.zeros((300, 1), dtype=torch.float64)

                classifier_loss = class_weights_torch * torch.maximum(- class_labels_torch * 
                                                           decision_distance,  zero_matrix)
                tf_dv_nn_train = nn_train_value - value
                stop_gra=value.detach()
                train_roa_labels_torch = torch.tensor(train_roa_labels, dtype=torch.float64)
                decrease_loss = train_roa_labels_torch * torch.maximum(tf_dv_nn_train, 
                                          torch.zeros([300,1])) / (stop_gra + OPTIONS.eps)
                # decrease_loss = train_roa_labels * tf.maximum(tf_dv_nn_train, 0)
                res = (classifier_loss + lagrange_multiplier * decrease_loss).mean()
                return res


           
            values = lyapunov_nn.lyapunov_function.forward(train_states)
            nn_train_value = 
                   lyapunov_nn.lyapunov_function.forward(dynamics.build_evaluation(train_states))
            objective = loss(values, nn_train_value)
            optimizer.zero_grad() 
            objective.backward() 
            optimizer.step() 

The structure of a neural network is simple：
kernel_0 = nn.Linear(4, 256)
kernel_1 = nn.Linear(256,256)
kernel_2 = nn.Linear(256,256)

I tried to save the computed graph but normally this training doesn't need to save the computed graph, after using .backward(retain_graph=True) the error is reported as RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.DoubleTensor [256, 256]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 3; expected version 2 instead.
Please teach me how to find the tensor which makes the errors.
